# django override model save() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to get `request` as a parameter in `save()` method.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    dob = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'profile'

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.user_id = 2  #here i need request.user instead of 2
        super(Profile,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ['uuid','user']
```

**views.py**

```
def add(request):
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    profile_form.save()
```

Instead of the value `2` i want to pass `request.user`. How can i do it. If question is not correct somebody please correct the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do that in the model. Do it in the view.

```
profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
if profile_form.is_valid():
    profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
    profile.user = request.user
    profile.save()
```

Comment: As Daniel says, don't create dependencies or insert view logic in your model, the view should be sufficient to handle your case.

Comment: @daniel roseman . If you don't mind could you please tell, problem that if use that in model..

Comment: Because the model shouldn't know anything about requests. For one thing, you might be calling the model from outside the request cycle altogether; in an async Celery task, or a manage.py command, or anything like that.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use [crequest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-crequest), like this:

```
# model
from crequest.middleware import CrequestMiddleware

class Profile(models.Model):
    # Some fields
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        crequest = CrequestMiddleware.get_request() #its the current request
        if crequest.user.pk is 1:
            # Do stuff
           pass
    super(Profile,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use kwargs.
For example:

views.py

```
profile_form.save(your_arg = request)
```

models.py

```
your_var = kwargs.pop("your_arg", None) #Second argument of kwargs.pop is default value
```

In you case, pass request as keyword argument, and then use it in models save() method.